# depends on or dependant on

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Consider the following:

> The response time of a service depends on the network traffic,
>
> The response time of a service dependant on the network traffic.

Which is correct?

Comment: The first, both in grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence is correct, while your second one is incorrect or incomplete.

Your second statement maybe rewritten as follow:

> The response time of a service **is** dependent on the network traffic

Or

> The response time of a service dependent on the network traffic, [details]

Comment: I'm unconfortable with your last 'dependent' usage because  it is unclear what part of speech this word is in that context!

Comment: @Xavier- Look at it this way: **The response time of a service , dependent on the network traffic, failed to achieve...**